# How to Parse DOM SOAP XML using PHP

Tags: php, soap, xml-parsing, namespaces

I would like to parse a XML which is in DOM type with Namespace. Following is the format of the XML.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns:ShowInventoryValue releaseID="" xmlns:ns="http://www.xxxx.com/oxit/oagis">
         <ns:ApplicationArea>
            <ns:CreationDateTime/>
         </ns:ApplicationArea>
         <ns:DataArea>
            <ns:Show/>
            <ns:InventoryValue>
               <ns:InventoryValueHeader>
                  <ns:Party role="WarehouseParty">
                     <ns:PartyIDs>
                        <ns:ID schemeName="PartyTypeNumber">001</ns:ID>
                        <ns:ID schemeName="PartyNumber">000123</ns:ID>
                        <ns:ID schemeName="PartySubNumber">000123</ns:ID>
                     </ns:PartyIDs>
                     <ns:Name sequence="1">W90</ns:Name>
                     <ns:Name sequence="2">India</ns:Name>
                  </ns:Party>
                  <ns:CustomerParty>
                     <ns:PartyIDs>
                        <ns:ID schemeName="EAN13">3938243</ns:ID>
                     </ns:PartyIDs>
                  </ns:CustomerParty>
               </ns:InventoryValueHeader>
               <ns:InventoryValueLine>
                  <ns:Item>
                     <ns:ItemID>
                        <ns:ID schemeName="article">1101960</ns:ID>
                     </ns:ItemID>
                     <ns:Specification>
                        <ns:Property>
                           <ns:NameValue name="centralized">Y</ns:NameValue>
                        </ns:Property>
                     </ns:Specification>
                  </ns:Item>
                  <ns:Quantity unitCode="ST" type="InTransitSum">0</ns:Quantity>
                  <ns:Status>
                     <ns:Code name="availability"/>
                  </ns:Status>
                  <ns:OxLocalization>
                     <ns:Party role="WarehousePartyCAC">
                        <ns:PartyIDs>
                           <ns:ID schemeName="PartyTypeNumber">009</ns:ID>
                           <ns:ID schemeName="PartyNumber">00056</ns:ID>
                           <ns:ID schemeName="PartySubNumber">00056</ns:ID>
                        </ns:PartyIDs>
                        <ns:Name sequence="1">W90</ns:Name>
                        <ns:Name sequence="2">India</ns:Name>
                     </ns:Party>
                     <ns:OxQuantityAvailability>
                        <ns:OxAvailability type="value1">
                           <ns:TypedQuantity unitCode="ST">0</ns:TypedQuantity>
                        </ns:OxAvailability>
                        <ns:OxAvailability type="value2">
                           <ns:TypedQuantity unitCode="ST">0</ns:TypedQuantity>
                        </ns:OxAvailability>
                        <ns:OxAvailability type="value3">
                           <ns:TypedQuantity unitCode="ST">0</ns:TypedQuantity>
                        </ns:OxAvailability>
                        <ns:OxAvailability type="value4">
                           <ns:TypedQuantity>0</ns:TypedQuantity>
                        </ns:OxAvailability>
                        <ns:OxAvailability type="value5">
                           <ns:TypedQuantity>0</ns:TypedQuantity>
                        </ns:OxAvailability>
                        <ns:OxAvailability type="value6">
                           <ns:TypedQuantity>0</ns:TypedQuantity>
                        </ns:OxAvailability>
                        <ns:OxAvailability type="value7">
                           <ns:TypedQuantity>0</ns:TypedQuantity>
                        </ns:OxAvailability>
                        <ns:OxAvailability type="value8">
                           <ns:TypedQuantity>0</ns:TypedQuantity>
                        </ns:OxAvailability>
                     </ns:OxQuantityAvailability>
                  </ns:OxLocalization>
               </ns:InventoryValueLine>
               <ns:InventoryValueLine>
                  <ns:Item>
                     <ns:ItemID>
                        <ns:ID schemeName="article">1101960</ns:ID>
                     </ns:ItemID>
                     <ns:Specification>
                        <ns:Property>
                           <ns:NameValue name="centralized">Y</ns:NameValue>
                        </ns:Property>
                     </ns:Specification>
                  </ns:Item>
                  <ns:Quantity unitCode="ST" type="InTransitSum">0</ns:Quantity>
                  <ns:Status>
                     <ns:Code name="availability"/>
                  </ns:Status>
                  <ns:OxLocalization>
                     <ns:Party role="WarehousePartyCAC">
                        <ns:PartyIDs>
                           <ns:ID schemeName="PartyTypeNumber">009</ns:ID>
                           <ns:ID schemeName="PartyNumber">00056</ns:ID>
                           <ns:ID schemeName="PartySubNumber">00056</ns:ID>
                        </ns:PartyIDs>
                        <ns:Name sequence="1">W90</ns:Name>
                        <ns:Name sequence="2">India</ns:Name>
                     </ns:Party>
                     <ns:OxQuantityAvailability>
                        <ns:OxAvailability type="value1">
                           <ns:TypedQuantity unitCode="ST">0</ns:TypedQuantity>
                        </ns:OxAvailability>
                        <ns:OxAvailability type="value2">
                           <ns:TypedQuantity unitCode="ST">0</ns:TypedQuantity>
                        </ns:OxAvailability>
                        <ns:OxAvailability type="value3">
                           <ns:TypedQuantity unitCode="ST">0</ns:TypedQuantity>
                        </ns:OxAvailability>
                        <ns:OxAvailability type="value4">
                           <ns:TypedQuantity>0</ns:TypedQuantity>
                        </ns:OxAvailability>
                        <ns:OxAvailability type="value5">
                           <ns:TypedQuantity>0</ns:TypedQuantity>
                        </ns:OxAvailability>
                        <ns:OxAvailability type="value6">
                           <ns:TypedQuantity>0</ns:TypedQuantity>
                        </ns:OxAvailability>
                        <ns:OxAvailability type="value7">
                           <ns:TypedQuantity>0</ns:TypedQuantity>
                        </ns:OxAvailability>
                        <ns:OxAvailability type="value8">
                           <ns:TypedQuantity>0</ns:TypedQuantity>
                        </ns:OxAvailability>
                     </ns:OxQuantityAvailability>
                  </ns:OxLocalization>
               </ns:InventoryValueLine>
            </ns:InventoryValue>
         </ns:DataArea>
      </ns:ShowInventoryValue>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

In the above XML I would like to parse ItemID and value1 typed quantity. I couldn't find proper resources in the online to parse the same. Please help me with the solution or give reference link to refer and parse. Most of the online resources are discussing about simple xml parsing. But I want to parse this tough XML.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I have tried like this :   $doc = new DOMDocument();
 $doc->load($fileName);
 $Itemcodes=$doc->getElementsByTagName("ns:ItemID");
 echo $Itemcodes->nodeName;
 foreach($Itemcodes as $ItemCode)
 {
 echo  $ItemCode->nodeName;
 
 
 }